# In the C language how do you use make multiple strings in separate variables

Tags: c, string, variables

In the tutorial I've been using it only shows one way to list strings

```
char * name[] = "blah and blah";
```

I'm confused because is name a actual command or is it just a name for the variable (name).

Comment: This is something that you could have tried yourself and find out the answer immediately.

Comment: I'm sure there is more than one tutorial out there, and you might find one that explains things better.

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial?

Comment: I've resolved this question and it turns out I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name`, in your case, is the actual name of the variable.

It is an array of char pointers. The first element of the array points to a string `"blah and blah"`.

Answer (score 0):

It's the name of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

From the title i guess you want to know this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    char * name[] = {"blah and blah", "second blah"};

    printf("%s\n", name[1]);
}
```